# Why does Android insist on squishing my Button?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a nice, pretty, facebook button image:

[image: My Regular Facebook Login Button]

But my Android layout keeps squishing it:

[image]

Could anyone please help, here is a look at my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tagline"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_description"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/tagline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/tagline"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tagline"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button_normal"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: 9-patch your image to explicitly indicate which part you allow to be redimensioned (i.e. none)

Comment: Is your button a 9 patch? if so, it's really poorly designed. I mean the 9 patch drawable markers.

Comment: @DerGolem its not 9 patch

Comment: @IllegalArgument But it looks like: it has a 1px black border on all sides. And this makes me think of a 9 patch (badly marked)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `Button` with a text inside. The property `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` applies on the width of the text, not on the width of your drawable background.

You can either:

- Integrate the text in your .png file.
- Use 9-patch
- Create a drawable to define the blue corners-rounded rectangle and create an image with only the white 'f' with the vertical line. Then you can use an `TextView` with a drawable inside:

  ```
   <TextView
       ...
       android:text="Log in"
       android:drawableLeft="{Your image (white f)}"
       android:background="{Your drawable (blue background)}"
       ... />
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you are setting the background to your button:

```
android:background="@drawable/login_button_normal"
```

android:background doesnot preserve the aspect ratio of the image. Try giving some big text then you might start wondering why it is enlarged. Also for your purposes a 9-patch png's are preferred.